# Find most frequent combinations of numbers in 2D list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional list. The inner lists are all filled with 6 random Integers between 1 and 45. I want to find out which three combinations of consecutive numbers are the most occurring for each combination length between two and four numbers and how often they actually occure. To keep it short I gave the example with only the most occuring number combinations but I think you get the point. My list and code I thought about:

```
intlst = [[29, 38, 17, 30, 33, 41], [12, 20, 30, 33, 29, 38], [12, 20, 30, 29, 38, 41], [17, 30, 33, 41, 33, 45], [27, 29, 17, 30, 33, 41]]
```

So the most occuring combination of consecutive numbers with a length of two numbers is: 29, 38 which occures three times.

The most occuring combination with three numbers is: 12, 20, 30 occuring two times.

The most occuring combination with four numbers is: 17, 30, 33, 41 occuring three times.

I want to print a result with additional text so a function would be great. This should look something like this:

```
def countcombinations(intlst, length):
    #do the math
    return result

    print("most occuring combinations with a length of two:",countcombinations(intlist, length),"\n most occuring combinations with a length of three:",countcombinations(intlist, length),"\n most occuring combinations with a length of four:",countcombinations(intlist, length))
```

So the output would look something like this:

```
most occuring combinations with a length of two: 29, 38 3x times
                                                 .., .. nx times
                                                 .., .. nx times


most occuring combinations with a length of three: 12, 20, 30 2x times
                                                   .., .., .. nx times
                                                   .., .., .. nx times


most occuring combinations with a length of four: 17, 30, 33, 41 3x times
                                                  .., .., .., .. nx times 
                                                  .., .., .., .. nx times
```

I was successful to get the result with a length of two using tuples but I don´t know how to do the same thing with three and four numbers long combinations.

Comment: You mean combinations of elements of same sublist only?

Comment: No, actually from all sublists.

Comment: Where's the complete example including expected result? Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

itertools.combinations is the best tool for this task. See below:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

def most_freq(l, n):
    temp=[]
    for i in l:
        temp.extend(tuple(k) for k in combinations(i, n))
    res = Counter(temp)
    return res

for i in range(2,5):
    print(most_freq(l, i))
```

Output for n=2:

```
l=[[2, 13, 30, 33, 39, 41], [17, 20, 27, 33, 39, 38]]

>>>print(most_freq(l, i))

Counter({(33, 39): 2, (2, 13): 1, (2, 30): 1, (2, 33): 1, (2, 39): 1, (2, 41): 1, (13, 30): 1, (13, 33): 1, (13, 39): 1, (13, 41): 1, (30, 33): 1, (30, 39): 1, (30, 41): 1, (33, 41): 1, (39, 41): 1, (17, 20): 1, (17, 27): 1, (17, 33): 1, (17, 39): 1, (17, 38): 1, (20, 27): 1, (20, 33): 1, (20, 39): 1, (20, 38): 1, (27, 33): 1, (27, 39): 1, (27, 38): 1, (33, 38): 1, (39, 38): 1})
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for... I didn´t want to get all combinations with the numbers already in the sublists. My idea was to count the already existing ones but thank you for your help!